# Get by id is generating error in Django/Mezzanine

Tags: django, mezzanine

```
def check(request):
       if request.user.is_authenticated:
        uid = request.user.id
        if AllUsers.objects.get(FK_id = uid):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

ERROR: DoesNotExist at /users/
AllUsers matching query does not exist.

How to solve this error?

**UPDATE:**
**Models:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from mezzanine.pages.models import Page
# The members of Page will be inherited by the Author model, such
# as title, slug, etc. For authors we can use the title field to
# store the author's name. For our model definition, we just add
# any extra fields that aren't part of the Page model, in this
# case, date of birth.

GENDER = (('male','Male'), ('female','Female'))
class AllUsers(models.Model):
    FullName = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    DOB = models.DateField()
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices = GENDER)
    HomeAddress = models.TextField()
    Contact = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    Email = models.EmailField()
    FK = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: can you show us your AllUsers model?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn;t use your `_id` property to retrieve Models connected via a Foreign Key.
Do this instead:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

And, in your view:

```
object_AllUsers = AllUsers.objects.get(user = request.user)
```

Also, you may want to use a OneToOneField, instead of ForeignKey.
See more about this here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey